# Two or more spring boot application sharing same port

Tags: spring-boot, port, executable-jar

I have a use case where I need to run atleast two or more spring boot applications on the same port.

I am able to run spring boot applications via `mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev... port and other information`. I have provided following configuration in spring boot projects

1. `server.port= 8597`
2. `server.contextPath=<as per the project>`
3. `spring.config.name=<project name>`

With this configuration, I successfully run two spring boot application on same port i.e. 8587.

Now, here the problem comes, when I package the project as jar for dist purposes and run the application as `java -jar <profile>....`. second boot project run fails with Address already in use.

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong. I even tried passing context, port and config name in vm arguments but no success.

Any help?

Comment: That's not directly possible, you either need to run a reverse proxy or use a standalone tomcat server and deploy your applications to it.

Comment: But I am able to do it through maven spring boot plugin bu when I do it through java jar. it does not work. I think, there is some configuration which is missing.

Comment: At the same time, at the same port? No, that's not possible.

Comment: Thinking of trying [this](http://davidtanzer.net/running_multiple_spring_boot_apps_in_the_same_jvm). Lets see how it goes.